# Girls Under 12 Champions.

Tags: apostrophe

Should there be an apostrophe in girls in the expression “Girls Under 12 Champions”

Comment: _Where_ do you think an apostrophe would be necessary? Depending on context, there _might_ be one in _champions_ but without context it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I’d be more concerned about the missing hyphen than the missing apostrophe.

Comment: It would be a guess without more context or providing the source.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an apostrophe, but I notice the capital letters. This means that this is a proper noun phrase, and for proper nouns, the apostrophe is sometimes omitted, especially when the noun is plural.

So this isn't necessarily an error.

Comment: It is also relevant that 'Girls Under 12' is a category, usually for girls who, on a particular day, are more than 10 but less than 12. Similar categories exist for 'Girls Under 14' and 'Girls Under 16', etc. If an apostrophe were used, it would need to be added after '12', not after 'Girls', so you would end up with 'Girls Under 12's Champions', which is slightly cumbersome to say.

Comment: It is quite common to see "Women's Under 18 Championship" (eg) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IIHF_World_Women%27s_U18_Championships So placing the apostrophe after "Girls" is not inappropriate